# How to browse remote Neo4j database? Is there any REST client?

Tags: database, rest, neo4j, graph-databases, graphenedb

Neo4j Server has its own browser. It allows to browse any local database. But currently I need to browse remote database. My remote Neo4j database provides REST API. I know its URL, login and password. How can I browse database via Neo4j Server browser or by any other means?

Comment: You can aslo change the neo4j-server.properties file to allow connection from 0.0.0.0 to the webbrowser

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen I have no control over remote server and I cannot to change any settings. I have only access to RESTful interface. So, it seems, that your advice don't fit my needs.

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky When you say browse you mean visually browse or a tool that will allow you to run queries etc.?

Comment: @albertoperdomo Perhaps will be enough just to view the results of the queries. But I doubt that there is a convenient way to do this without visualization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, if the REST API is exposed, the browser UI will be too.
Assuming the REST endpoint is https://user:pass@somehost:7474/db/data/, opening https://user:pass@somehost:7474/ will open the browser UI. This can be accessed remotely from you local computer.

In fact, at [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com) we host remote instances for our users and this is how they access the browser.

If for some reason (don't know exactly why), you can't use the built-in browser remotely, there are other options:

If a CLI tool is good enough you can use [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#command-line). It comes with a CLI tool called `cypher` that is able to run queries against a remote server secured with HTTP basic authentication.

If you are looking at visual tools to explore a remote dataset there are multiple options:

- [Linkurious](https://linkurio.us/)
- [Popoto.js](http://www.popotojs.com/)

Comment: Information about accessing browser at GraphneDB was very helpful for me. It is exactly what I need. Many thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to see I was able to solve your problem!

Answer (score 3):

Current option is to download Neo4j source code, extract browser and change it for your needs.

https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.3/community/browser

Another option is to use some REST client like https://www.sprintapi.com/ and use [Neo4j REST API](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api.html)

Or wait for [Neo4j Sync](http://neo4j.com/neo4j-sync/), which could be an option.

Neo4j Sync announcement - https://youtu.be/xzPVPkK86zs?t=38m35s

Comment: Many thanks for this interesting answer. All is understandable except last part. Can you explain for me what is Neo4j Sync? I have visited product page, but it contains not enough information. My understanding is vague still.

Comment: @VictorDombrovsky I added announcement video